# if statement for checking if string with non standard characters is within another string is not working

Tags: python-2.7, character-encoding, pycharm

So say I have the following code:

```
a = 'naïve' # It contains the character ï
b = 'some text that may or may not contain the word we are looking for'
if a in b: #error happens here
    print 'success'
```

I'm trying to see if `a` is within `b` but it apparently doesn't know how to take in and work with unicode characters that are not english-standard.
It throws me the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file app.py on line 10, but no encoding declared
```

I am not sure what to do or try. Any clues? Thank you.

Comment: [An informative read](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Answer (score 0):

Put this line at the top of your file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: is there anyway to do that instead but with the `json` library or some string function like `encode()` in the code itself? I don't think I am allowed to modify the input file.

Comment: You could also do `unicode(non_ascii_text)` for both and that will do essentially the same thing.

Comment: @Yokhen or use Python3 :)

Comment: ^_^ I'd love to use python 3, but then again, I have a few retrictions.
I tried doing `if unicode(a) in unicode(b):` but it changed nothing. Getting same error.

Comment: try doing `a = unicode(text)` I think it might be a parsing error that just doesn't get caught right away.

Comment: Woops, I misread the documentation. try doing `unicode(text, "UTF-16")